# Larave Blade component named slot: Possible typo $svg - Did you mean $svg?

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade, slot

Laravel:

> Possible typo $svg - Did you mean $svg?

Well yes, yes I did!

I'm trying to make use of a Blade Component with a [Scoped Slots](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#slots)

I've got a navbar-link component:

```
@props([
    'svg',
    'route',
])

<a href="{{ route($route) }}" class="w-full focus:text-teal-500 hover:text-teal-500 justify-center inline-block text-center pt-2 pb-1">
    <div {{ $svg->attributes->class(['inline-block']) }}>
        {{ $svg }}
    </div>
    <span class="tab tab-home block text-xs">{{ $slot }}</span>
</a>
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
<x-navbar-link route="home">
    <x-slot name="svg">
        <svg width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="inline-block mb-1">
            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                ...
            </g>
        </svg>
    </x-slot>
    Index
</x-navbar-link>
```

But then I get:

#### ErrorException

Undefined variable $svg (View: ...

#### Possible typo $svg

Did you mean $svg?

Which kinda doesn't make any sense.. at first glance at least.

What am I missing?

Comment: how does the controller looks like?

Comment: May be you are missing proper routing or compact problem from your controller

Comment: This is a bladed component with a named slot. It has nothing to do with my controller as far as I understand: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#slots